# Android HTTPUrlConnection SocketTimeoutException/Indefinite Hang?

Tags: java, android, json, http, post

I'm working on an Android app for a client, and I'm calling their API to get the info for various parts of my app. There is one call that results on SocketTimeoutException if I set a timeout, or infinitely hangs if I don't; however, it works just fine on the web client(React), so it can't be the server.

Code:

```
package io.voluntu.voluntu;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SendApproveHours extends AsyncTask<Bundle, Void, String>{
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    private String result;
    private ApproveHours approveHours;

    public SendApproveHours(ApproveHours approveHours){
        this.approveHours = approveHours;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Bundle... params){
        Bundle b = params[0];
        String jwt = b.getString("JWT");
        System.out.println(jwt);

        boolean approve = b.getBoolean("APPROVE");
        int[] id = b.getIntArray("ID");
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://voluntu.io/api/hour/update");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(2500 /* milliseconds */); //if i don't do this, it will hang indefinitely
            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(1500 /* milliseconds */);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Host", "voluntu.io");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Origin", "http://voluntu.io");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://voluntu.io/hours/approve");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "sessionJWT=" + jwt);

            httpURLConnection.connect();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("approveOrReject", approve);
            jsonObject.put("hourIDs", Arrays.toString(id));

            System.out.println(jsonObject);

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int HttpResult = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode(); //hangs here
            System.out.println("HTTP RESULT: " + HttpResult);
            if(HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                       httpURLConnection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"
                ));
                String line;
                while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                in.close();
            }
            System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + sb.toString());
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        approveHours.refreshHours();
    }
}
```

It hangs on getting the HTTP response code for some reason. I checked the headers and body and they are identical to what the web version is sending, so I have no idea why it's not working. Also, calling other parts of their API works just fine, and in fact this code is mostly copy pasted from other parts of my app that call the API. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Instead of an array, you must use JSONArray, or the array gets wrapped in quotes when it gets put in the JSON object.